# Converting if/and statement into an array formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, logic, array-formulas, logical-operators

I'd like to convert the following formula:

```
=IF(A2:A=1,"Under an hour",IF(AND(A2:A<48,A2:A>23),"1 Day",IF(A2:A>=24,int(A2:A/24)&" Days",ROUNDUP(A2:A) &" Hours")))
```

into an Array formula. Currently it doesn't work because AND statements don't work in Array Formulas but I'm not really sure how to get it working without the and (and without embedding 24 different IF statements)

I basically just want to return user-readable text in column B relating to how many hours are shown in A:

```
0   0 Hours
1   Under an hour
2   2 Hours
23  23 Hours
24  1 Day
25  1 Day
47  1 Day
48  2 Days
49  2 Days
100 4 Days
```

Comment: Presumably this is not Excel since your range syntax would only work in Sheets?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's sheets, I didn't realise the range syntax was different, Should I untag Excel or does the if statement work the same in both?

Comment: Unless you need it to work in both, I'd untag Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `AND(A2:A<48,A2:A>23)` to `(A2:A<48)*(A2:A>23)`:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Do you understand why this works? What would you need to do to an OR statement?

Comment: @JoeW ```AND``` is an array function - it receives an array of parameter values and returns a single value, so it will not work with ```ARRAYFORMULA``` as you intended. In turn, multiplication works with each element of the array separately and in this case also returns the array. And ```IF``` function converts zero values to ```FALSE``` and nonzero to ```TRUE```.

Comment: @JoeW For ```OR``` change mutiplication to addition, i.e. ```*``` to ```+```.